# Why does double edge razor blade not sinks but single edge razor blade sinks in water?

Tags: everyday-life, surface-tension

We often see that we can make a double edge razor float on water due to surface tension acting at some angle on all four sides to balance the weight i got this part , but when a single edge razor blade is placed there akso on four sides the surface tension forces can balance it , what difference does it means by saying double edge and single edge ?

Comment: Balance perhaps? Tilting lifts the other end out so it displaces less water than its weight. Try nudging the double edged razor on one end into the water.

Comment: I am not understanding the difference between double edge floating and single edge sinking @DKNguyen

Comment: The center of gravity is a bit to one side in the single ended blade,

Comment: Oh so the only difference is the centre of mass location other things all remains same tension forces acting at angle theta and mg downwards?

Comment: That's my theory anyways; That the single ended blade doesn't sit flat in the water and that is just enough to make it lift enough out of the water on one end and sink similar to how a vertically dropped blade sinks.

Comment: Is it true by the way that surface tension in case of single one , all still will be having some angle theta made , there cannot exists a situation where in one-two sides angle is different from the other two sides for force balance in single case?

Comment: I don't know anything about surface tension and I'm not really sure it is even relevant here with regards to staying afloat.

Comment: Have you weighed both sorts of blade? The single-edged ones that I've encountered seem to be made of a thicker metal than the double-edged ones.

Comment: Another possibility: Single edged blades are made from two pieces of metal, There's a sort of folded-over clippy piece on the back side. If the finish on the clippy piece was hydrophilic, then that would break the surface tension, and the whole assembly would be pulled under by its weight.